# undefined array warning during isset usage

Tags: php

How can I check if a variable is set in PHP? If I am using isset it still throws an error `Warning: Undefined variable`

```
 if (isset($_POST['newContext'])) {
     $newContext = $_POST['newContext'];
 }
```

**Background:**

My JavaScript file passing `const = newContext` to my PHP. This variable is in use like 80% of each executons. I want to get rid of the PHP warning message for the remaining 20% and only set the passed variable if this is not empty. How can I do it?

Comment: Please check the full error message and check exactly where that warning is thrown. I don't see how the posted code can throw it (it also complains about "variable", not "index" or "array key"). My bet is that you're using `$newContext` later on, but only define it in this if-statement (which means that the variable `$newContext` won't be defined later on if `$_POST['newContext']` isn't set)

Comment: isset() is a language construct and not a normal function. It dont throw warnings of undefined variables

Answer (score 0):

Had an old loop included, definetely as Eriksson mentioned, it wasn´t the method